# How can i check if all CustomResourceDefinitions have been created properly?

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform

I have installed with success cert-manager following [the steps indicated here](https://docs.cert-manager.io/en/latest/getting-started/install/kubernetes.html).

Now, i am doing an script that checks if every steps are done properly, so my question is: How can i check if all the CustomResourceDefinitions are created via kubectl, for example?

I use google kubernets engine v1.13

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This command works: `kubectl get CustomResourceDefinition | awk '{ print $1 }'`

You can use `-o yaml` or `-o json`